# What exactly is decltype(std::get<0>(tup))?

Tags: c++, types, template-meta-programming, stdtuple

I am currently learning metaprograming in C++, and I'm trying to see whether an element of a tuple is a pointer. I tried this approach:

```
int a = 3, b = 4;
auto tup = std::make_tuple(&a, b);
std::cout << std::is_pointer<decltype(std::get<0>(tup))>::value; //prints 0
```

I thought this was strange, so I examined the type clang deduced (I'm using clang-10), which is

```
__tuple_element_t<0UL, tuple<int *, int>
```

And it looks like some internal type.

Why do I get this weird type and what would be the proper way to get the actual type of an element of the tuple? I have only a solution which uses an intermediate `auto` variable, but is hardly optimal.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`std::is_same`/`std::is_same_v` can be very helpful in TMP and, when looking for types being equal to other types, it's invaluable when used in conjunction with `static_assert`.

With the following code you can see that `std::get` gives you a reference to the element of the tuple (as confirmed by [cppreference's page on `std::get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get)), in this case `int*&`, where `int*` is the type of the element. If you use it to initialize *another* variable you get a copy of it (so no more reference for `elem`, just `int*`), just like `int x = r;` defines `x` to be a copy of `r` regardless of `r` being a reference or not.

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>

int main() {
    int a = 3, b = 4;
    auto tup = std::make_tuple(&a, b);
    auto elem = std::get<0>(tup);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(elem), int*>,"");
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(std::get<0>(tup)), int*&>,"");
}
```

As regards your attempt, the fact that the second `static_assert` above is passing, explains why `std::is_pointer<decltype(std::get<0>(tup))>::value` prints `false`/`0`: that is a *reference* to `int*`, not an `int*`. On the other hand, the following *does* print `true`/`1`:

```cpp
std::cout << std::is_pointer_v<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(std::get<0>(tup))>>;
```

See that I've used `is_pointer_v` instead of `is_pointer` and `is_same_v` instead of `is_same`? Those with `_v` are helper metafunctions that give you the `value` member of the non-`_v` metafunctions.  `remove_reference_t` works similarly with respect to `remove_reference`, but giving the `type` member.

Answer (score 4):

As [Enlico explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64301615/5825294), the type you were getting was a reference.
In addition to his answer, I'd say you can get the actual type of the element of the tuple more easily with:

```cpp
std::tuple_element_t<0, decltype(tup)>
```

Comment: User's name is "Enlico", not "Enrico" ;-)